# Laravel Query ((or and or) or) and

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So I am a bit stuck in this query I need to do.

So let me try to explain my problem.
I receive the following in my method in the model:
$a, $b and $c.

But the $b and the $c might be null.

So my query need to be something like this
select * from `pushnotifications` where ((`from_user_id` = $a or `to_user_id` = $a)  and (`from_user_id` = $b or `to_user_id` = $b) or (`to_user_id` = $a and `from_user_id` = 0)) and id=$c

Answer (score 2):

Use nested `where()` and `orWhere()`:

```
Model::where(function($q) {
    $q->where('from_user_id', $a)
      ->orWhere('to_user_id', $a)
})->where(function($q) {
    $q->where('from_user_id', $b)
      ->orWhere('to_user_id', $b)
})->orWhere(function($q) {
    $q->where('from_user_id', $a)
      ->orWhere('to_user_id', $0)
})->where('id', $c)
->get();
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but there is still some problems. First, the $b might be null. If that happens this returns invalid results. And the last where ('id', $c), is not filtering as it should.

Comment: I will out the query resulting from that `select * from `pushnotifications` where (`from_user_id` = ? or `to_user_id` = ?) and (`from_user_id` = ? or `to_user_id` = ?) or (`to_user_id` = ? and `from_user_id` = ?) and `id` < ?`

Comment: Dont forget to inherit the variables from the parent scope though!